# Can child elements of a display:box parent maintain their defined height instead of all becoming the same height?

Tags: css

I've set up a JS fiddle of what I'm working with. http://jsfiddle.net/bjankord/2EKQv/
It seems if I add a height to one of the child elements of a parent with display:box set, all the other child elements stretch to that height. I don't know if this is how the display:box and box-ordinal-group properties are supposed to work, if so that's unfortunate. I was hoping to be able to reorder my html markup with CSS using box-ordinal-group when working on responsive web designs, but this height issues is killing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am by no means a flexbox expert but from some quick testing I think you might need to change your layout to be three vertical columns and add box-orient:vertical to each of the parent elements. In order to have one child element taller than the others set the box-flex: property to 2 on your withHeight class and set the min-height of that class to 300px;

**Fiddle:**
So I messed with your code a bit. I added a parent container with box-orient:horizontal to line up the three columns and gave each column box-orient:vertical. This seemed to fix the issue with height not being respected.

http://jsfiddle.net/mdJ2L/1/

Comment: Interesting. I'm with you on being new to flexbox. It seem's like it has potential to solve some of the layout issue we have currently with html/css.

Thanks for the answer!